# Equal sign `=` doesn't include in URL in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a hyperlink which has `=` sign at the end of it. When I route to this link, the equal sign automatically disappear from the URL which results in Link Expired message.

Actually, We have a reset password functionality in which a link is being mailed to a user to reset their password. In that link, there is a token attached and that token has `=` sign at the end of it. While hitting the API, we need to pass that token in payload but due to missing of `=` sign it doesn't get me 200 response.

Below is the link I am getting in my Email (see it has `=` at the end of it):

http://localhost:4200/reset-password/eyJpZCI6Ik5qSm1NR0l4TldWaE1USTFaV1U1WVRSaU5ESmlZMlEzIiwiZGF0ZSI6MTY2MDEwODM1Mzk5NH0=

Below is my code:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.auth = this.route.snapshot.params['auth'];
  console.log(this.auth);  //eyJpZCI6Ik5qSm1NR0l4TldWaE1USTFaV1U1WVRSaU5ESmlZMlEzIiwiZGF0ZSI6MTY2MDEwODM1Mzk5NH0
}

// Here in this.auth not getting equal (=) sign at the end of it
```

Now I am passing `this.auth` in my payload. But it doesn't have `=` sign hence gives me an error of link expired.

Any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: `=` is a special character in a URL to denote query parameter assignment so if you want to use it as a character you can URL encode it to `%3D`

Comment: Use router.navigate() it will take care of special characters, even on reload. did you try? 
else you can use encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent

Comment: @Alex I am getting token from the URL using `ActivatedRoute` as shown in the code above so there is already `=` omitted. How can I encode it to `%3D` if there is no `=` in URL?

Comment: @SajinSatheesan I just defined my routing for reset-password component. When I click the link that I received in my Email, it automatically routed me to reset-password component. Moreover, how can I use `encodeURIComponent`? Can you please write some example for me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that '=' has meaning in url(for query string). You should use '='  with url encoding. And backend should decrypt it and use.

Comment: Is there any other way to generate token at backend which doesn't include `=` sign? Also, I need to encode that at frontend using `atob()`

Comment: Ofc, You can generate it on backend without contains any '='